# DOS/16M: Error message [6] Not enough memory loading INFORMIX-SE 4.10.DD6 engine

Tags: memory-management, dos

INFORMIX-SE 4.10.DD6 on DOS 6.22 ((DOS16M=3):

I'm trying to run a protected mode Informix-SE engine executable but im getting the error message described in the title of this post. DEVICE=C:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS is the first entry in my CONFIG.SYS and MEM.EXE says I have 616K of REAL MEM available. I'm using using DOS16M switch = 3 and the executable is only 546K size.

Comment: It's a known issue, its fixed in DOS 7.0 :)

Comment: @Yannis: cannot upgrade to 7.0, im running native DOS 6.22, not under windows. 6.22 was last pure version of DOS and my software INFORMIX-SQL only runs on 6.22

Comment: Sorry, previous comment wasn't to be taken seriously :)

Comment: Have you tried DOSBox? (semi-seriously)

Comment: @rwong: I copied some DOS4G protected mode utilities to my DOS 6.22 but that didnt work. I cannot switch from DOS 6.22 so I must find a way to solve problem in it.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for either superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: @Dolph: Well, I don't think so because its related specifically to INFORMIX-SQL and someone with legacy ISQL experience might be able to solve my problem, so leave it alone!

Comment: @Frank: Hey, I'm not voting to close, I'm just making a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem myself. Used /INT15=8192 option with HIMEM.SYS to force extended memory manager to pre-allocate 8MB of extended memory using hardware interrupt 15h versus XMS specification method. ISQL 4.10.DD6's target OS was for DOS 5.0 and I am using DOS 6.22, in which HIMEM.SYS 3.0 uses XMS specifications for managing extended memory.